# Quick idea for a shuffling algorithm - would this work?

Tags: algorithm, random

I was discussing with my brothers a quick-and-dirty algorithm for shuffling a deck of cards (i.e. an array in which every element is unique). Description of the algorithm:

Let the number of cards in the deck be `n`. Take a number `x` so that `gcd(n,x)=1`. Now iteratively pick the card number `(x*i) mod n` for `i=1` up to `i=n` and put it in a new pile of cards (*without* removing the card from the original deck, that is, make a copy of the card). The new pile of card will be our result.

It seems clear to me that only performing this algorithm once will not give a result that is "random enough" (in the sense that it would fail statistical tests for determining randomness). But what if we perform the algorithm iteratively, possibly for a new value of `x` that also fulfills `gcd(n,x)=1`? If doing this a sufficient number of times would give us a "random enough" result, how many times could we expect to need to do this as a function of `n`?

Comment: Why would you want to create a dubious and expensive algorithm when there are [excellent efficient algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) already available?

Comment: @pjs I am only interested in this theoretically, not as a practical solution to a problem.

Comment: How would you pick `x` or rather what will you pick for `x`? For `gcd(n, x)` to be `1`, `x` must be least prime number greater than `n`. So putting `n = 10, x = 11`, you will end up with identical deck.

Comment: @YuHao The first operation in any shuffling algorithm does not result in a shuffled deck, but doing the same operation iteratively sometimes works.

Comment: @HarshGupta Good point! Of course I require x to be between 1 and n.

Comment: @Sid, if you pick `x` to be greatest prime number less than `n`, even then it might not always work. Put `n = 12 and x = 11`.

Comment: @HarshGupta Yeah you're right in the sense that it would return the exact same deck, so it would make the "shuffle" poor. Some choices for x are better than others I suppose.

Comment: @ Sid: congrats, you reinvented the Weyl generator... Any coprime of n will do, there is no requirement for x to be prime or greater than n. Weyl generators can be extremely useful, especially if x is chosen to be close to the golden ratio (or some other nice irrational) relative to n, since then every new value will fall squat into the largest remaining gap and divide it in the golden ratio. However, for shuffling it sucks. pjs has linked the Fisher-Yates which is hard to beat for that purpose. If you want every hand of a 52-card deck to be possible you need a huge generator with 226+ bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it multiple times would be insufficient due to the wonders of modulo arithmetic. In fact, there are at most `n` permutations you could ever achieve this way, and that's precisely when `n` is prime or 1.

Suppose you were to do this twice, with `x` relatively prime to `n` the first time and `y` relatively prime to `n` the second time.

The first time an element at position `p` is moved to `p * x (mod n)`. Then the second time it is moved to `(p * x) * y (mod n)`. This is the same as moving it to `p * (x * y) (mod n)` because of the associative nature of modular arithmetic. But if `x * y = v (mod n)` then it's the same as moving it to `p * v (mod n)` -- and as you know, there aren't more than `n` equivalence classes.

Hence, there are at most `n` permutations that could be resulted in a `n`-length deck. (No, this isn't a rigorous proof!)

**Edit:**

I had claimed if you used modular multiplicative exponentiation instead, it would be superior. However, after additional consideration many trivial configurations would still fall prey to modular arithmetic in the same "at most `n` permutations" way.